# Jekyll Deployment fails but local website works

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, portfolio, uglifier

I am using the [ai-folio](https://github.com/alshedivat/al-folio#deployment) template for a website. Everything worked until this time. I have a master branch where the files are updated. The gh-pages branch does the deployment. Locally, I can run
 `bundle exec jekyll serve`
and see that my website was change on e.g. one single page. Basically, the preview presents no issues.
In the repository, if I call
 `bin/deploy --user`
to deploy the website on Github Pages, I get a very long error, and the page does not remotely deploy.

Two questions:
1- how do I solve this?
2- is there a way to make Git deploy my page if it is in the remote master branch from the browser?

The error is copypasted below.

```
 Jekyll 4.3.2   Please append `--trace` to the `build` command 
                     for any additional information or backtrace. 
                    ------------------------------------------------
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/uglifier-4.2.0/lib/uglifier.rb:291:in `parse_result':  (Uglifier::Error)
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/uglifier-4.2.0/lib/uglifier.rb:221:in `run_uglifyjs'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/uglifier-4.2.0/lib/uglifier.rb:166:in `compile'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/htmlcompressor-0.4.0/lib/htmlcompressor/compressor.rb:546:in `compress_javascript'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/htmlcompressor-0.4.0/lib/htmlcompressor/compressor.rb:502:in `block in process_script_blocks'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/htmlcompressor-0.4.0/lib/htmlcompressor/compressor.rb:501:in `map!'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/htmlcompressor-0.4.0/lib/htmlcompressor/compressor.rb:501:in `process_script_blocks'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/htmlcompressor-0.4.0/lib/htmlcompressor/compressor.rb:490:in `process_preserved_blocks'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/htmlcompressor-0.4.0/lib/htmlcompressor/compressor.rb:216:in `compress'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-minifier-0.1.10/lib/jekyll-minifier.rb:79:in `output_html'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-minifier-0.1.10/lib/jekyll-minifier.rb:32:in `output_compressed'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-minifier-0.1.10/lib/jekyll-minifier.rb:182:in `write'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:231:in `block in write'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:363:in `block in each_site_file'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:363:in `each'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:363:in `each_site_file'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:230:in `write'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:82:in `process'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.2/lib/jekyll/command.rb:28:in `process_site'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.2/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:65:in `build'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.2/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:36:in `process'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.2/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `block in process_with_graceful_fail'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.2/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `each'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.2/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `process_with_graceful_fail'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.2/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `block in execute'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `each'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `execute'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/program.rb:44:in `go'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary.rb:21:in `program'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.2/exe/jekyll:15:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/bin/jekyll:25:in `load'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/bin/jekyll:25:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.17/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `load'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.17/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `kernel_load'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.17/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:23:in `run'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.17/lib/bundler/cli.rb:492:in `exec'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.17/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.17/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.17/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.17/lib/bundler/cli.rb:34:in `dispatch'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.17/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.17/lib/bundler/cli.rb:28:in `start'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.17/exe/bundle:37:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.17/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:117:in `with_friendly_errors'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.17/exe/bundle:29:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
        from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What was the change on that one single sheet?